# How to print the JSON data object in folder structure format using plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj = [{
    name: 'files',
    children: [{
        name: 'local',
        children: [{
            name: 'Doc1'
        }, {
            name: 'Doc2'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'public'
    }, {
        name: 'private'
    }]
}];

var text = "";
function printFolders(obj) { 
 for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
   text+= obj[i].name + '\n';
    if(obj[i].children){
     printFolders(obj[i].children);
    }
  }    
}

printFolders(obj);
console.log(text);
```

I am trying to convert following object into a folder structure and print it. I have tried some logic and it worked to print the files in the order as expected but I am missing the logic to format it with spaces.

I have following object data

```
var obj = [{
    name: 'files',
    children: [{
        name: 'local',
        children: [{
            name: 'Doc1'
        }, {
            name: 'Doc2'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'public'
    }, {
        name: 'private'
    }]
}];
```

and I am expecting the output in the following format:

```
-files
  -local
    -Doc1
    -Doc2
  -public
  -private
```

Is there any way to add those spaces logically and maintain the level? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass another parameter level to printFolders function, then print folder name with different spaces by level.

If you want "-" before each folder name, you can also add "-" between spaces and folder name.

```js
var obj = [{
    name: 'files',
    children: [{
        name: 'local',
        children: [{
            name: 'Doc1'
        }, {
            name: 'Doc2'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'public'
    }, {
        name: 'private'
    }]
}];

var text = "";
function printFolders(obj, lvl) { 
 for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
   text+=" ".repeat(lvl*2) + obj[i].name + '\n';
    if(obj[i].children){
     printFolders(obj[i].children, lvl+1);
    }
  }    
}

printFolders(obj,0);
console.log(text);
```